# Divisibility and the Fibonacci Sequence Proof

Tags: fibonacci-numbers

> Let $F_n$ be the Fibonacci sequence ($F_1=1, F_2=1, F_3=2, \ldots F_n$ such that $F_n = F_{n-1} + F_{n-2}$). Show that $F_n$ divides $F_{rn}$ for all $r,n \ge 1$.

I'm not sure how to show this rigorously. I feel that eventually the terms repeat and so $F_{nr} = qF_n$, where $q$ is an integer.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r46WR.png)

(I attached the problem in an image since I used LaTex with my intuition.) I thought about using induction but got nowhere and am completely stuck. How would I start and what would I need to show? This is for an introductory number theory class.

Comment: Forgot something?

Comment: Sorry, I fixed it.

Comment: The Fibonacci sequence: $F_n = F_{n-1} + F_{n-2}$  Now substitute $F_{n-1} = F_{n-2} + F_{n-3}$ into the previous.  Keep doing it.  Can you find a pattern?  Derive a new formula for the sequence such that $F_n = F_k\times \text {Something} + \text {Something else}$ and then show that if $k$ divides $n, F_k$ is a factor of both terms.

Comment: I found the equality F_n = F_{k+1} F{n-k} + F_k F{n-k-1}. The problem is if I decompose F_{k+1}, I get two terms, so I can't factor F_k from the equality stated.

Comment: If you have additional work, add it to the original post, rather than as a comment.  Don't decompose $F_{k+1}$  If our proposition is true then $k|n \implies F_{k}|F_{n-k}$  Now you can start thinking about a proof by induction

Comment: @DominatedConvergenceTheorem Please do not replace the question details with a "thanks" post. That qualifies as defacement and should never be done; doing so can get you in trouble.

Answer (score 0):

I'll prove a slightly more general result.

Suppose that $F_n\equiv 0 \bmod k$, and $F_{n+1} \equiv c \bmod k$. Then of course immediately $F_{n+2} \equiv 0{+}c$ $\equiv c \bmod k$ and thus $F_{n+i} \equiv  cF_i \bmod k$ and $F_{2n+i} \equiv  c^2F_i \bmod k$ etc.

In particular $F_{rn} \equiv c^{r-1} F_n$ $\equiv c^{r-1}{\cdot\,} 0$ $\equiv 0 \bmod k$.

In the specific case of this question, set $k=F_n$.

Comment: In my question on [Fibonacci pseudoprimes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2193215/fibonacci-pseudoprimes) I was given some terminology, "rank of apparition" which led me to [this paper](http://www.fq.math.ca/Scanned/1-2/vinson.pdf)